# Exo player 2.8.2 always starts with lo bandwidth stream

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, exoplayer2.x, adaptive-bitrate

I have an android app where using exoplayer 2.8.2 for playing HLS streams. It's working with adaptive bit rate but it always starts with the lowest stream instead of a higher stream even on a very high-speed network. I have tried to set the default max initial bandwidth to Integer.MAX_VALUE but it is not working.

```
final long defaultMaxInitialBitrate = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
 DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder()
          .setInitialBitrateEstimate(defaultMaxInitialBitrate)
          .build();

 TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
 new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

 trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

 player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getContext(), trackSelector);

 DataSource.Factory mediaDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getContext(), Util.getUserAgent(getContext(), getString(R.string.app_name)));

  if (currentGalleryModel.mediaUrl != null) {
 mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse(currentGalleryModel.mediaUrl),
 mediaDataSourceFactory, null, null);
 player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
 player.prepare(mediaSource);
 }
```

Does someone know how I pick a higher bandwidth stream by default?